# convert android mac address hexstring into byte[] in java

Tags: android, mac-address

```
 WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 String macAddress = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
```

it is a String in hex format, for example:

```
"00:23:76:B7:2B:4D"
```

I want to convert this string into a byte array so that I can use `MessageDigest` sha1 on it

I got it worked in Python by using the excaping `\x` instead of `:` using the `hashlib` module.

But I would I do it in android/java? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
Byte.parseByte(mac[i], 16);
```

Not parse correctly hexadecimals numbers started with letters: "AE", "EF", etc...
Revised code:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wm != null) {
    String[] mac = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress().split(":");
    byte[] macAddress = new byte[6];        // mac.length == 6 bytes
    for(int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
        macAddress[i] = Integer.decode("0x" + mac[i]).byteValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
byte[] macAddress = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress().getBytes();
```

Revised Solution:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String[] mac = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress().split(":");
byte[] macAddress = new byte[6];
for(int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {            
    macAddress[i] = Byte.parseByte(mac[i], 16);
}
```

Comment: In this context, `getBytes` will return the 34 Unicode code points rather than the 6 bytes of the MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

By this you get mac address in byte array so you no need to convert it.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class App{

   public static void main(String[] args){

    InetAddress ip;
    try {

        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

        NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

        byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

        System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SocketException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

   }

}
```

/*Copy from here : copy from http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/comment-page-1/#comment-139182*/

Answer (score 0):

In android API level 28, there is an easier way of doing this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/MacAddress.

```java
android.net.MacAddress.fromString(s).toByteArray();
```